# VisualForce Button not returning Selected Ids

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning

I am converting a custom List JS button to support lighting. So, I've made changes to existing class and created a VF page and added that to the list view button. But when I run the functionality nothing seems to happen and debug logs returned Id as 000000.. Pls suggest.

```
global class AddUserToTeam{
    public Opportunity objOpp;
  
    global AddUserToTeam(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdcontroller) {
        objOpp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
        system.debug(objOpp );
    }
    public pagereference addTeam(){
          List<Id> opportunityIds = new List<Id>();
          opportunityIds.add(objOpp.Id);
          system.debug('oppid'+ opportunityIds);
          addTeamMember(opportunityIds);
          //return new pagereference(url.getsalesforcebaseurl().toexternalform()+'/'+objOpp.Id);
          return new PageReference('/006/o');
    }
    webservice static boolean addTeamMember(List<Id> opptyIds)
    {
    // some logic to add a user to teams
    }
    
VF
```

<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" recordSetVar="Opportunities" extensions="AddUserToTeam" action="{!addTeam}">
</apex:page>

```
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V3vp.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, check the below code

```
global class AddUserToTeam{
    public Opportunity objOpp;
    public String accIds{get;set;}
  
    global AddUserToTeam(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdcontroller) {
        System.debug('Get Selected');
        objOpp = stdcontroller.getSelected();
        accIds = '';  
        for(Opportunity acc : objOpp){
            accIds += acc.Id + ','; 
            System.debug('Opp ID : '+accIds);
        }
        accIds = accIds.removeEnd(','); 
    }
    }
    public pagereference addTeam(){
          List<Id> opportunityIds = new List<Id>();
          opportunityIds.add(accIds );
          system.debug('oppid'+ opportunityIds);
          addTeamMember(opportunityIds);
          return new pagereference(url.getsalesforcebaseurl().toexternalform()+'/'+accIds );
          //return new PageReference('/006/o');
    }
    webservice static boolean addTeamMember(List<Id> opptyIds)
    {
    // some logic to add a user to teams
    }
```